# Independence of collections of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Suppose we have three random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ on the same probability space such that the collections $\{X_1,X_2 \},\{X_2,X_3\}$ and $\{ X_3,X_1 \}$ are mutually independent.Note that this is different from saying that each collection is independent,i.e. they are not pairwise independent. So, can we say $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ is independent?

I feel that they are not independent but I can't find a valid counter example. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The mutual independence of $\{X_1, X_2\}$, $\{X_2, X_3\}$, and $\{X_3, X_1\}$ refers to, by definition, the fact that $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(X_1, X_2)$, $\sigma(X_2, X_3)$, and $\sigma(X_3,X_1)$ are mutually independent. Now it is easy to verify:

> **Lemma.** If the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}_1, \dots, \mathcal{F}_n$ are mutually independent and $\mathcal{G}_i\subseteq\mathcal{F}_i$ are $\sigma$-sugalgebras, then $\mathcal{G}_1, \dots, \mathcal{G}_n$ are also mutually independent.

From this, we know that $\sigma(X_1) \subseteq \sigma(X_1, X_2)$, $\sigma(X_2) \subseteq \sigma(X_2, X_3)$, and $\sigma(X_3) \subseteq \sigma(X_3,X_1)$ are mutually independent, which in turn implies the mutual independence of $X_1, X_2, X_3$.

Comment: Does your example take care of the case of mutual independence of  $\{X_1,X_2\},\{X_2,X_3\},\{X_3,X_1\}$? I mean independent as a collection .. not that $X_1,X_2$ are independent  among themselves

Comment: @IronMaiden42, I edited my answer just now. Hope this correctly addresses your question.

Comment: how do you define $\sigma (X_1 ,X_2) $?

Comment: @IronMaiden42, It may be defined by several equivalent ways: $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\sigma(X_1)\cup\sigma(X_2)$, or it is the sigma algebra generated by the random vector $\omega\mapsto(X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega))$.

Comment: So, it may happen that $\sigma(X_1) \cup \sigma(X_2)$ is not a $\sigma$ field? As it is the union of two $\sigma $ fields

Comment: @IronMaiden42. Indeed you are correct. The mere union need not be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: So, how can you tell $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ is a $\sigma$ field?

Comment: @IronMaiden42, I am not sure why you are asking this, because $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ is **defined** as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\sigma(X_1)\cup\sigma(X_2)$.

Comment: ohh ok it is the sigma algebra of the unions right?

Comment: @IronMaiden42, That is correct. Any version of the $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ should be able to describe the idea of "the minimal collection of information arising from $X_1$ and $X_2$", and the aforementioned definition is one of the several (equivalent) ways of realizing this.

Comment: Ok , I know that independence of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ refers to the independence of the sigma fields generated by them, so can we extend it directly that independence of $\{X_1, X_2\} $ and say $\{X_2, X_3\}$ implies independence of $\sigma(X_1,X_2) $ and $\sigma(X_2,X_3)$ , doesn't this require a proof?

Comment: @IronMaiden42, Again, that is because of the definition (or at least a version of this that I learned). If this is not what you know about independence, please direct me into the version of the independence of the families of RVs that you are using. That I may explain using them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maybe you are looking for the answer to a more elementary question: Pairwise independence of random variables in general does not imply joint independence. Consider the following counter example: Suppose two fair six sided dice are independently rolled, and let $X_1=1$, if the first die is 1, and zero otherwise, $X_2=1$ if the second die is 1, and zero otherwise, and $X_3=1$ if the sum of the rolls is 7, and zero otherwise. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are clearly independent. It is a little work, but a good exercise, to show $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent, and similarly $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent. However 
$P(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=1)=0 \ne P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)P(X_3=1)>0$, so $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ are not mutually independent.